# Scale UI for multiple resolutions/different devices

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have a quite simple unity GUI that has the following scheme :

[image]

Where Brekt and so are buttons.

The GUI works just fine on PC and is on `screen space : overlay` so it is supposed to be adapted automatically to fit every screen.

But on tablet the whole GUI is smaller and reduced in the center of the screen, with huge margins around the elements (can't join a screenshot now)

What is the way to fix that? Is it something in player settings or in project settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatically scaling the UI requires using combination of anchor,pivot point of `RecTransform` and the [`Canvas Scaler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html) component. It is **hard** to understand it without images or videos. It is very important that you thoroughly understand how to do this and Unity provided full video tutorial for this.You can watch it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezeoYnLBpnE).

Also, when using scrollbar, scrollview and other similar UI controls, the [`ContentSizeFitter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html) component is also used to make sure they fit in that layout.

Comment: Hum i thought it was automatically adaptable thanks to screen overlay... I'm a beginner in c# and it looks quite hard to do this way, but if there are no other solutions...

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with MovementRange. We must scale this value too.
I did it so:

```
public int MovementRange = 100;
    public AxisOption axesToUse = AxisOption.Both; // The options for the axes that the still will use
    public string horizontalAxisName = "Horizontal"; // The name given to the horizontal axis for the cross platform input
    public string verticalAxisName = "Vertical"; // The name given to the vertical axis for the cross platform input
    private int _MovementRange = 100;

    Vector3 m_StartPos;
    bool m_UseX; // Toggle for using the x axis
    bool m_UseY; // Toggle for using the Y axis
    CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis m_HorizontalVirtualAxis; // Reference to the joystick in the cross platform input
    CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis m_VerticalVirtualAxis; // Reference to the joystick in the cross platform input

    void OnEnable()
    {
        CreateVirtualAxes();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        m_StartPos = transform.position;
        Canvas c = GetComponentInParent<Canvas>();
        _MovementRange = (int)(MovementRange * c.scaleFactor);
        Debug.Log("Range:"+ _MovementRange);
    }

    void UpdateVirtualAxes(Vector3 value)
    {
        var delta = m_StartPos - value;
        delta.y = -delta.y;
        delta /= _MovementRange;
        if (m_UseX)
        {
            m_HorizontalVirtualAxis.Update(-delta.x);
        }

        if (m_UseY)
        {
            m_VerticalVirtualAxis.Update(delta.y);
        }
    }

    void CreateVirtualAxes()
    {
        // set axes to use
        m_UseX = (axesToUse == AxisOption.Both || axesToUse == AxisOption.OnlyHorizontal);
        m_UseY = (axesToUse == AxisOption.Both || axesToUse == AxisOption.OnlyVertical);

        // create new axes based on axes to use
        if (m_UseX)
        {
            m_HorizontalVirtualAxis = new CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis(horizontalAxisName);
            CrossPlatformInputManager.RegisterVirtualAxis(m_HorizontalVirtualAxis);
        }
        if (m_UseY)
        {
            m_VerticalVirtualAxis = new CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis(verticalAxisName);
            CrossPlatformInputManager.RegisterVirtualAxis(m_VerticalVirtualAxis);
        }
    }


    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {
        Vector3 newPos = Vector3.zero;

        if (m_UseX)
        {
            int delta = (int)(data.position.x - m_StartPos.x);
            delta = Mathf.Clamp(delta, -_MovementRange, _MovementRange);
            newPos.x = delta;
        }

        if (m_UseY)
        {
            int delta = (int)(data.position.y - m_StartPos.y);
            delta = Mathf.Clamp(delta, -_MovementRange, _MovementRange);
            newPos.y = delta;
        }
        transform.position = new Vector3(m_StartPos.x + newPos.x, m_StartPos.y + newPos.y, m_StartPos.z + newPos.z);
        UpdateVirtualAxes(transform.position);
    }
```