# UI text is not rendered but appearing in hierarchy — what is missing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

trying to show text dynamically created to the canvas but its not rendering.
After creating canvas an empty gameObject attached as child and the following script is attached to that. After running the object appears in hierarchy but not rendered.maybe I'm missing something:

```
GameObject o;

void Start() {
    GameObject test = new GameObject("myTextGO");
    test.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
   // test.transform.SetParent(o.transform);

    Text myText = test.AddComponent<Text>();
    myText.text = "Hello there!";
 }
```

Also tried few other combination but not text is not rendering. Need to know solution.

Comment: Do you need a RectTransform?

Comment: Its just a line of text. Is it reqruied? I tested by reseting transform in play mode but did not appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things required to do when creating UI text dynamically and **manually**:

- Font
- Proper Parenting
- RectTransform (Now, automatically attached by Unity when UI component
  is attached to a GameObject)

I assume that you are using the latest Unity version so you just need to do the first two:

Supply font for the Text component to use as mentioned [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51189916/3785314) answer. Also, when using `transform.SetParent`, you have to supply `false` to it. This causes the UI component to keep its local orientation.

```
void CreateText(GameObject canvas, string text)
{
    //Create Canvas Text and make it child of the Canvas
    GameObject txtObj = new GameObject("myTextGO");
    txtObj.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);

    //Attach Text,RectTransform, an put Font to it
    Text txt = txtObj.AddComponent<Text>();
    txt.text = text;
    Font arialFont = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font>("Arial.ttf");
    txt.font = arialFont;
    txt.lineSpacing = 1;
    txt.color = new Color(50 / 255, 50 / 255, 50 / 255, 255 / 255);
}
```

Usage:

```
public GameObject canvas;

void Start()
{
    CreateText(canvas, "Hello there!");
}
```

---

That's how to create a text component manually *but that should no longer be used*. Let Unity do this automatically. The [`DefaultControls`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.DefaultControls.html) should be used to create UI Objects. It reduces the chances that the creation code will fail or that you'll run into similar issues in your question. Create the `Text` resources with [`DefaultControls.Resources`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.DefaultControls.Resources.html) then the `Text` itself with [`DefaultControls.CreateText`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.DefaultControls.CreateText.html).

```
void CreateText(GameObject canvas, string text)
{
    DefaultControls.Resources uiResources = new DefaultControls.Resources();
    GameObject uiText = DefaultControls.CreateText(uiResources);
    uiText.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
    uiText.GetComponent<Text>().text = text;

    //Change the Text position?
    //uiText.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(100f, 100f);
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation. How can I make the uiText size automatically/dynamically grow if the string grows? and retrieve its other instances position for multiple method calls?   for     //uiText.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(getWidth/*/viceVersa, 100f);

Comment: "automatically/dynamically"....This is not done with `sizeDelta`. Read and watch the video linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652812/scale-ui-for-multiple-resolutions-different-devices/37652982#37652982)

Comment: Can you mention How can I stack text objects for such multiple method calls?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "stack text objects for multiple method calls". Can you create new question?

Comment: Sure. I will post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no font attached to the Text-object.
Try adding this line

```
myText.font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font>("Arial.ttf");
```

Comment: Yeah. It worked. Wonder why tutorials wont mention this?

Comment: Great! There are some bad tutorials out there im afraid.

Comment: Can you please mention how to set its position to (0,0)? The created child has a odd position. This is not working:     test.transform.position = new Vector3(0.0f, 1f, 0.0f) ;

Comment: Try using test.transform.localPosition instead