# How to add spacing dynamically on unity gameObject added to scrollView?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to add text elements on scrollview each having its own space.

For the code below after creating object added to the empty gameObject that is child of scrollview. Now if I add manually hight and width it works but if the string size grows it will become zagged again. So need to know what its previous elements height is or add space/padding to the top.

[Heres the code from other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189690/ui-text-is-not-rendered-but-appearing-in-hierarchy-what-is-missing) to create and adding those textObjects:

```
void CreateText(GameObject canvas, string text)
{
    //Create Canvas Text and make it child of the Canvas
    GameObject txtObj = new GameObject("myTextGO");
    txtObj.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);

    //Attach Text,RectTransform, an put Font to it
    Text txt = txtObj.AddComponent<Text>();
    txt.text = text;
    Font arialFont = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font>("Arial.ttf");
    txt.font = arialFont;
    txt.lineSpacing = 1;
    txt.color = new Color(50 / 255, 50 / 255, 50 / 255, 255 / 255);

    //requriing a solution like this only dynamically.
    txt.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(100f, 200f);
}
```

How can I add spacing dynamically here for following loop? So that they are readable as different text objects.

```
for (i;i<10;i++)
    //CreateText(canvas, UserText+" Hello there! "+i);
    CreateText(canvas, "Hello there! "+i);
```

---

---

Require the text object to increase size automatically which is not achieved with content fitter attached to the empty gameObject. Default GridLayoutGroup cell  and col size is 100x100, need to increase it dynamically.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier if you have an example screenshot of what you're shooting for because Unity may have this built-in.

Comment: Have you tried the ContentSizeFitter? It would take care of sizing appropriately regardless the size of the items.

Comment: `GridLayoutGroup` check it.

Comment: Thank you all. I updated the question with screenshot. Please see this.